# Finding the dominant term of an integral (asymptotic expansion)

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, laplace-method

Let $I(\lambda)=\int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$. We want to find the dominant term of $I(\lambda)$. For this problem, I wonder whether my approach is correct or not, and where my solution fails if it does.

The first way of solving this problem is that letting $t=\lambda + s$ yields the following integral,
\begin{align}
I(\lambda) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda^2 -2\lambda s -s^2}ds, \\ I(\lambda) &= e^{-\lambda^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\lambda s} e^{-s^2}ds.
\end{align}
Then for another change of variable, let $2s=u$ so that
\begin{align}
I(\lambda) &= \frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda u} e^{-u^2/4}du, \\
I(\lambda) &= \frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda u}(1-u^2/4+\dots)du,\\
I(\lambda) &= \frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2}\bigg[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda u}-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^2e^{-\lambda u}du+ \dots\bigg],\\
I(\lambda) &= \frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{\lambda} - O(1/\lambda^3) \bigg), \\
I(\lambda) &\sim \frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}.
\end{align}

I tried to solve this problem with a different approach. So what I observe is that  the maximum value of $-t^2$ over $[\lambda,\infty)$ is taken at $\lambda$. Then I substitute the Taylor expansion of $-t^2$ about $t=\lambda$ and get 
\begin{equation}
I(\lambda) \sim \int_{\lambda}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda^2 -2\lambda(t-\lambda)}dt.
\end{equation}
Let $u=t-\lambda$, then we have
\begin{equation}
I(\lambda) \sim \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda^2 -2\lambda u}du,
\end{equation}
and solving this integral gives that
\begin{equation}
I(\lambda) \sim \frac{e^{-\lambda^2}}{2\lambda}.
\end{equation}
I do not know what is wrong with my solution, I would be happy if you share your opinions.

Comment: The second solution is not wrong, but you haven't proved that yet. $-(t - \lambda + 1)^2$ also attains its maximum at the left endpoint, but
$$\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-(t - \lambda + 1)^2} dt \not \sim
\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-1 - 2 (t - \lambda)} dt.$$

Comment: I am sorry Maxim, I couldn't have caught what you said.

Comment: I'm just saying that if you formally apply the same procedure to my example, you'll get a wrong result. You need to justify why the method is applicable to your example.

Comment: I am sorry but I have the same results here, both integrals yield $1/2e$ as a dominant term.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think your answer is wrong?
The fact that you got the 
same answer in two ways
should be strong evidence
that your answer is correct.

See, for example,
equation 16 here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html

Comment: Let's say a friend thinks it is wrong, what is valid is the first solution as he thinks.

Comment: What does this friend think is wrong?

Comment: We are following Logan's Applied Mathematics book (I hold the 3rd edition), it covers the topic with the integral $\int_a^be^{\lambda g(t)}dt$ (see page 148), where $\lambda >> 1$, however in my case, the constant on the power of $e$ is $1$, therefore he rejects this as far as I understand.

Comment: That result does not apply in this case, but all that means is that you have to use a different result. You could use $1 > e^{-x} > 1-x$ for $x > 0$ to bound the error of the approximation.

Comment: This still does not respond why we cannot use Laplace Method even if the method gives the correct result, or when this method is eligible for smaller values of $\lambda$. Maybe I do not understand why this method is defined large (how large?) values of lambda.